# CSS3 font-face … how to make font-style:italic to use the actual italic version?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, embedded-fonts

I have two embedded fonts - a regular and a "real" italic version …

```
@font-face {font-family: 'MyFont-Regular';src: url('wf/2061CF_2_0.eot');src: url('wf/2061CF_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('wf/2061CF_2_0.woff') format('woff'),url('wf/2061CF_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
@font-face {font-family: 'MyFont-RegularItalic';src: url('wf/2061CF_6_0.eot');src: url('wf/2061CF_6_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('wf/2061CF_6_0.woff') format('woff'),url('wf/2061CF_6_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-style:italic, oblique;}
```

I'm using the italic version on a few classes …

```
.MyFont-RegularItalic, .italic, em { font-family: MyFont-RegularItalic; }
```

I'm applying `MyFont-Regular` on my `body` and I have an element `div.example` where I want the text to be italic.

In order to achieve this I would have to apply this …

```
div.example {
    font-family:MyFont-RegularItalic;
}
```

This works of course fine. However, since I'm already applying the "regular" version of the font to my `body` I wonder if I can somehow make `font-style:italic;` work for this as well. So I don't want to apply the entire `font-family` again but simply declare it as italic.

```
div.example {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

This doesn't work and leads to a browser-slanted italic version of the "regular" font - the real "italic" fontface is not used in this case.

Any ideas or tricks if it is possible to make my stylesheet automatically use the "real" italic version of the font when I apply `font-style:italc` to an element.

Thank you in advance,
Matt

update:

[image: Screenshot of the two cases]

Comment: did you convert real italic "MyFont-RegularItalic" or you converted normal font?

Comment: Well, yeah those are two different "faces". So I have a regular fontface and a "real" italic font face. I updated my question with an image of the two cases. The first line uses `font-family:MyFont-RegularItalic;` and is CORRECT! the second line has just `font-style:italic` applied and is now a just a slanted version of the "regluar" font. If you can't tell the difference at the first glimpse just compare the a's.

Comment: Please Add


font-face {
    font-family: "name";
    src: url("fonts/name.ttf");
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}

Comment: I updated my question with your code but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: http://www.jqueryin.com/2010/07/06/css3-font-face-with-bold-and-italic/       May be this will help you

Comment: hey, you call separate, I dont know it will work or not but im guessing there is a chance to work.   font-face { font-family: "name"; src: url("fonts/name.ttf"); font-style: italic, oblique; }

Comment: Where is the difference to the comment before?

Comment: i read it from  another place same like this question , i told you "I dont know it will work or not" , Did you try?

Comment: Yep, doesn't have an effect for me. It's of course not that big of a deal - I can simply apply the font-family to my div. I was just wondering if I could make `font-style:italic` for as well. In my case it doesn't. I tested it just in Chrome right now, maybe it would work in other browsers, but it doesn't matter. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Add the style to the font declaration.

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"MyFont";
  src:url("myfont.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family:"MyFont";
  src:url("myfont-italic.ttf");
  font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't seem to make a difference. I applied `font-style:italic;` to my `@font-face` declaration but when just using `font-style:italic;` on any element now it is still a slanted version of the regular font - not the real italic. See my updated sample screenshot.

Comment: Works fine for me. Just tested with defining a non-italic font to use for font-style:italic and it is rendered correctly: https://skitch.com/lxndr/87q7x/font-issue